# Categorizing different types of likes on a post and displaying it using AJAX php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, social-likes

I want to create a LIKE BUTTON for 3 separate columns in my table, which I have created using Handsontable. On clicking any of these like buttons the response should be taken and sent to a PHP file. The PHP file, fetches the data and processes the SQL query to update the number of likes on the post. The required system is exactly like any other LIKE BUTTON feature (For Ex: Instagram).

Columns in the table:

1. Employee Name
2. Employee ID
3. Rank (For the top 3 best targets)
4. Goal Comment
5. Goal Commit
6. Result (target reached: O/X)
7. Reply Comment
8. Goal Comment Like (like button corresponding to 4. Goal Comment)
9. Goal Commit Like (like button corresponding to 5. Goal Commit)
10. Reply Comment Like (like button corresponding to 7. Reply Comment)

Column 8,9 and 10 are displayed within column 4,5 and 7 respectively since they represent like button using *innerHtml* and a custom Renderer like this:

```
function detailRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    if (col == 4) {
        if (value != null && instance.getDataAtCell(row, 8) != null){
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
            cellProperties.readOnly = false;
            td.innerHTML =   '<div class="like">'+value+'<div class="in-like" style="color:red;"><i class="far fa-heart"></i>' + instance.getDataAtCell(row, 9) + '</div</div>';
            console.log(instance.getDataAtCell(row, 8));
        }
        else if(value != null && instance.getDataAtCell(row, 8) == null){
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
            td.innerHTML =   '<div class="like">'+value+'<i class="far fa-heart" style="color:red;"></i></div>';
        }
        else{
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
    else if (col == 6) {
        if (value != null && instance.getDataAtCell(row, 9) != null){
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
            td.innerHTML = '<div class="like">'+value + '<div class="in-like" style="color:red;"><i class="far fa-heart"></i>' + instance.getDataAtCell(row, 9) + '</div></div>';
        }
        else if(value != null && instance.getDataAtCell(row, 10) == null){
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
            td.innerHTML = '<div class="like">'+value+'<i class="far fa-heart" style="color:red;"></i></div>';
        }
        else{
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
    else if (col == 8) {
        if (value != null && instance.getDataAtCell(row, 10) != null){
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
            td.innerHTML = '<div class="like">'+value + '<div class="in-like" style="color:red;"><i class="far fa-heart"></i>' + instance.getDataAtCell(row, 11) + '</div></div>';
        }
        else if(value != null && instance.getDataAtCell(row, 10) == null){
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
            td.innerHTML = '<div class="like">'+value+'<i class="far fa-heart" style="color:red;"></i></div>';
        }
        else{
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    } 
    else{
        Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

This is my AJAX function which I know is definitely wrong since I am new to AJAX:

```
$(document).on("click", ".in-like", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var likesCounter = hot.getDataAtRowProp(row, 9);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/mycommit/like.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'challengeId': '{{challengeId}}',
                'userId': '{{SYANM}}',
                'likesCounter': '{{likesCounter}}',
                type: 'POST',
            },
            success: function(data) {
                likesCounter = data;
                console.log(likesCounter);
            },
        });
    });
```

My PHP file is:

```
<?php
use service\LoginService;
use util\TwigCommon;
use util\DbUtil;

$out = array();
$challengeID = $_GET['challengeID'];
$userID = $_GET['userID'];
$likesCounter = getLikesCounter($challengeID, $userID);

$out['SYANM'] = $_SESSION["login"]["SYANM"];
if(LoginService::hasRole(['system'])){
    $out["systemUser"] = 1;
}
else {
    $out["systemUser"] = 0;
}
$out['challengeID'] = $challengeID;
$out['userID'] = $userID;
$out['likesCounter'] = $likesCounter;

function getLikesCounter($challengeID, $userID){
    $params = array();
    $params['challengeID'] = $challengeID;
    $params['userID'] = $userID;

    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT COUNT(*) as likesCounter from HB_MYC_LIKES
    WHERE CHALLENGE_ID = :challengeID
    SQL;
    $result = DbUtil::query($sql, $params);
    $list = array_values($result);
    foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        $list[$key]['GOAL_COMMIT_LIKES'] = count($list[$key]['GOAL_COMMIT_LIKES']);
        $list[$key]['GOAL_COMMENT_LIKES'] = count($list[$key]['GOAL_COMMENT_LIKES']);
        $list[$key]['REPLY_COMMENT_LIKES'] = count($list[$key]['REPLY_COMMENT_LIKES']);
    }
    return $list;
}
//-----------------------------------------------//
/*This is just an attempt for different approach*/
//-----------------------------------------------//

if(isset($_GET('challengeID'))) {
    $challengeID = $_GET['challengeID'];
    $likesCounter = getLikesCounter($challengeID, $userID);
    echo json_encode($likesCounter);
}
```

I am unable to understand how to get categorized LIKES data, currently this code is taking just likes if it exists without categorizing and I do not want to assign separate value to each like column in the frontend. Instead I want to do it in the backend with the PHP file. Since I am a beginner to this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You define `$params['userID']`  but don't use it in your query `SELECT COUNT(*) as likesCounter ...`. So mysql should give an error

Comment: Because the SQL doesn't require USERID. The UserID is there for login authentication during the LoginService DAO

Comment: I can only add two cents from a Handsontable perspective. You can also use the `afterOnCellMouseDown `hook (ref: https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/api/hooks/#afteroncellmousedown) to track clits on that 'like' element. It gives you the column coordinate.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help, i kinda figured it out on how to make it work. But i havent finished it since im stuck on UPSERT in the backend, but if you want, I'll update an answer, just let me know.